# Is it possible to download json data (containing paths to videos, images, audio, etc) using QRCode and react js from browser to mobile?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on my thesis and I have to do a website tha manages some VA guides and a VA app for android using Unity.
I was wondering if I can download different types of multimedia (videos, images, audio) directly to the phone using a QRcode?
Just like we do if we download games from the store.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Yep. Just `JSON.stringify(jsonObj)` embed the returned string in QR. When the data is received back. `JSON.parse(receivedString)` to covert it back to a JSON object.

Comment: @TomBombadil I think I'm understanding you. So after that, the download of a video starts right away? that is confusing me ahahahahha